# LyX imports \'{e} as é. That messes the characters up at export time. How to keep it literal?

Tags: lyx, tipa

I use LyX only for LaTeX outlining and doing copy/paste surgery on my big file. I don't ever intend to print from LyX, since the time taken to make sure it handles all my packages and graphics imports properly isn't worth it.

But when I export plain TeX from LyX, all my carefully input **tipa** characters are messed up at export time. This means exporting destroys all my tables and examples.

Is there a setting for LyX that tells it not to interpret special fonts at all, just leaving \'{e} as it is?

Before importing into LyX:

[image: Before importing]

When in Lyx it looks like:
[image]

After exporting again, some of the characters have been translated into non-ascii and they are now apparently some other encoding:

[image]

Just to be clear: \'{e} is not the only character that does this. It's just a small example.

Here is the code from the comment:

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{llll}
    \ipa{/p\'{3}pr/ (\SL \UL)} & \rightarrow & \ipa{/p\'{e}.pa/ (\SL \UL)} & pepper' \\
    \ipa{/p\'{e}:pr/ (\SH \UL)} & \rightarrow & \ipa{/p\'{e}.pa/ (\SL \UL)} & paper'
    \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

After export from LyX:

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{llll}
    \ipa{/p\'{3}pr/ (\SL \UL)} & \rightarrow & \ipa{/p?.pa/ (\SL \UL)}
    & pepper' & & & & \tabularnewline
    \ipa{/p?:pr/ (\SH \UL)} & \rightarrow & \ipa{/p?.pa/ (\SL \UL)}
    & paper' & & & & \tabularnewline
  \end{tabular}
  \par
\end{center}
```

Comment: Can you give more information? Can you give a minimal example and the exact commands you run after you export from LyX?

Comment: [code]Original text:


\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ l l l l}
\ipa{/p\'{3}pr/ (\SL \UL)} &  \rightarrow & \ipa{/p\'{e}.pa/ (\SL \UL)} & `pepper' \\ 
\ipa{/p\'{e}:pr/ (\SH \UL)} &  \rightarrow & \ipa{/p\'{e}.pa/ (\SL \UL)} & `paper' \\ 

\end{tabular}
\end{center}



After export from LyX:


\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ l l l l}
\ipa{/p\'{3}pr/ (\SL \UL)}  & \rightarrow  & \ipa{/p?.pa/ (\SL \UL)}  & `pepper'  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\ipa{/p?:pr/ (\SH \UL)}  & \rightarrow  & \ipa{/p?.pa/ (\SL \UL)}  & `paper'  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
\par\end{center}

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the code there?

Comment: Edited with code as pictures.

Comment: Sorry to be so picky, but can you please mark the code as code in the question? In the edit box there is a button you can press. This makes it easy to copy/paste.

Comment: Sorry, no, Scott, that doesn't work. I'm afraid this is as clear as it gets. The code is all .png images so you'll have to just link to them if you want to copy/paste.

Comment: It sounds like LyX has set an encoding to utf8.  Can you turn that off before importing?

Comment: Wrong end, Andrew. Even if Lyx imported \'{e} as é and then exported it again as é, I would be unable to use it.  Well, not unable, but would be less happy. Ideally I would like Lyx to output the same characters as it inputs.

Comment: @SteveRapaport can you please post a minimal working example? I'm sorry for not linking to this the first time I asked: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample  A minimal example includes e.g. `\documentclass{`. For example, in your export from LyX, you only start with `\begin{center}`.